# PositionTwo elements in an array with given sum

Tags: algorithm

How do I find such elements in an array such that their sum is equal to a given number k.For example, there is an array {1,2,4,1,1,5} and k=2 so the elements are {1,1},{1,1,{1,1}. Now I saw a problem here which gives the solution to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259515/given-an-unsorted-array-find-any-two-elements-in-the-array-whose-sum-is-equal-t.

Now I was interested to know if there was any way to find the positions of these elements, that is their position in the array. By position I mean their index number in array. If I use sorting then the position of the array would get change, so I guess I can't use that.Is there any optimal algorithm to find the positions. If I use hashing and the given array has duplicates then  there would problem.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in O(n+m) on average, using a hash-map. (`n` is the array's size, `m` is the size of the output).

Just store each element while traversing and its index. Once you find an element that its complement to k is already in the map - print the two indices (one you have from the iteration and one is the value from the map).

Pseudo-code (using multimap semantics - each element can have multiple values attached):

```
map <- empty hash map
for each e in array at index i:
    if e is in map:
        print i, map.get(e) //current index and already stored indices
    map.add(k-e,i) //add the element to the hash map
```

Comment: What if there are duplicates? Suppose{1,1,4} and sum=5

Comment: @user220789 The multimap semantics will print the dupes, that's the idea. If you don't want this behavior - switch to 'regular' map, and make sure to invalidate elements after they were already printed.

Comment: I donot know much about this, can I implement it in c or c++, if I can please can you provvide me a link from where I can know more about its implementation, thank you, btw can it handle large number of inputs size like 10^4 or 10^5?

Comment: @user220789 quick googling gave me [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/), I am not a C++ expert, but the concept of map is fairly simple, it is basically very similar to AD.Net's solution of using a map that each value is actually a list.

Comment: Thanks,something is better than nothing.

Comment: By the way do you know whether this can handle large inputs or array sizes?

Comment: Just to note - there are O(n^2) pairs in the worst case (e.g. `1,1,1,...,1`, k = 2), so that's the worst-case running time of any algorithm to do this.

Comment: @user220789 It depends how 'large' do you mean. It requires O(n) space, but it is relatively fast method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` and populate it with the items and their indices. 
Example `{1, (0,3,4)},{2,(1)}` and then check each in the array, and see if you have `K-item` in the dictionary with `different index` than of item. 
BTW, you can do this at the same time as you iterate through the array, so the runtime is `O(n)`.